# Is it possible to access the C++ source code for SCIP?

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization, scip, sat

I would like to ask if it is possible to access the C++ source code for the main() program. I looked in the directories and am unable to find it.
The reason being is that I would like to trace the code to see how SCIP handles SAT problems, and perhaps modify the code to test out new ideas for the SAT problems that I am facing.
In the SCIP interface, I see

SCIP>

To which I read in my txt file and it prompts me for a file reader.

I then key in 'cnf'.

I then set my time limits and type 'optimize' to run the code.

I would like to trace the main code for this and print out some additional information which may be useful.

Comment: This might be interesting for you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59557794/how-does-the-scip-code-treat-sat-problems/59560687#59560687

Comment: I guess he is aware of the other question and your answer to it because he asked it in the first place ;)

Comment: Oops I did not realize, sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I have edited my query to try to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The sources of SCIP are available [here](https://scip.zib.de/index.php#download).

[image]

However if the source code of a software is not available to download but you really want it and you have a build of the software, you can dig into Reverse Engineering.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried digging into that but to no avail, because i would like to trace the code to a certain point and print out some outputs for greater understanding of my problems at hand.

Comment: You can find the function they call when using the SAT solver by following the functions calls. You can also find their maths [here](https://scip.zib.de/doc/html/WHATPROBLEMS.php)